# what is the differences between ego-motion and odometry

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I mean in 3D lidar. like LOAM, we say odometry estimation always means estimate the x,y,z,roll,pitch and yaw between two scans of lidar. but recently, I found the ego-motion seems also about this problem. so , what is the difference between the two "wrod" means?
thx for your help so much!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296686/what-is-the-differences-between-ego-motion-and-odometry/) by [mjjdick](https://answers.ros.org/users/31787/mjjdick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A possible slight difference could be that ego-motion is more about the estimation of the twist (linear and rotational velocities, both 2D or 3D cases), and odometry is the estimation of the path. In some cases, like in wheel odometry, this path estimation is computed by means of time-integration of an estimated twist. But in other cases, like classic visual odometry or scan matching, the poses are directly estimated, without performing any time-integration.

Anyway, I don't think that a strong consensus exist within the community about that, so you should take into account the context.

---

Originally posted by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) with karma: 169 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both words can be used interchangeably in general.

Ego-motion is defined as the 3D motion of a system (ex camera) within an environment.

Visual odometry or odometry in general is the estimation of egomotion using computer vision techniques.

---

Originally posted by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) with karma: 70 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1